# react-bootstrap dropdown not showing the dropdown arrow

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

React-bootstrap has following snippet [here](https://react-bootstrap-v4.netlify.app/components/dropdowns/#customization):

```
<DropdownButton id="dropdown-basic-button" title="Dropdown button">
    <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-1">Action</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-2">Another action</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-3">Something else</Dropdown.Item>
</DropdownButton>
```

It renders as follows:

[image]

However, when I copy pasted same in my code, it does not show any drop down arrow:

[image]

Why is it so?

PS: I have following in my package.json:

```
"react-bootstrap": "^1.4.3",
"bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
```

Comment: hi MsA, seems like your react-boostrap dep is 1 major version below the current one (2.XX) , have you tried updating this package?

Comment: Yes I know that, however the linked version is also older one.

Comment: What you have [should work](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-https-fepj0u?file=/src/App.js). Which means the source of the bug is in code you haven't shared yet. This makes your question *off-topic*, for being unanswerable, therefore useless to everyone, including yourself. Consider providing a *runnable* [mcve] reproducing the bug. My guess is you have custom CSS  overriding Bootstrap's default styles.